# Problem with keeping alive master and slave in a proprietary communication protocol

Tags: c, delay, uart, packet, stm32cubeide

I'm writing a UART communication protocol for my stm32l152c-discovery. Briefly, the master sends the communication start packet to the slave via the user button and the slave, if it receives it correctly, sends an ack start packet and passes to the connected state. In the same way, if the master receives the ack start packet correctly, it goes into connected state. In this state, master and slave keep alive with keep alive packets that must be sent every TPOLL which can be from 100 to 5000 milliseconds. If the TSILENT timeout, which is TPOLL + 100 milliseconds, expires, the board disconnects. The event counter is managed by a timer which increments every millisecond.

I encounter a low solidity problem, in fact after a few packets exchanged one of the two boards disconnects, I tried with various TPOLL values. If I increase TSILENT from TPOLL + 100 to TPOLL +1000 the program works correctly. The problem is that I have no delay in the operations I perform in this state and all the functions to be performed take 12 milliseconds (also counting the 10 for UART reception).timer 3 is initialized before entering the connected state. I've posted parts of the code that might be of interest.

```
void TIM3_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim3);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_IRQn 1 */

  GlobalTick++;

  if(GlobalTick == 1)
  {
      TX_BufferReset();
      SendPacket(KEEP_ALIVE);
      HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&huart3, TX_Buffer.buffer, TX_Buffer.count);
  }

  if(GlobalTick - t_event_poll >= TPOLL)
  {
      TX_BufferReset();
      SendPacket(KEEP_ALIVE);
      HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&huart3, TX_Buffer.buffer, TX_Buffer.count);
      t_event_poll = GlobalTick;
  }

  if(GlobalTick - t_event_silence > TSILENT)
  {
    state = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
    ResetTime();
  }

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_IRQn 1 */
}
```

```
    case STATE_CONNECTED:   
        RX_BufferReset();
        HAL_UART_Receive(&huart3, RX_Buffer.buffer, MAX_PKT_BYTES, 10);

        if(WaitFullPacket() == TRUE) 
            if (ReceivePacket() == CORRECT && RX_Buffer.buffer[3] == KEEP_ALIVE)
                t_event_silence = GlobalTick;
                break;
```

Comment: Those buffer reset calls look very troublesome.  In the bottom snippet, you'd expect WaitFullPacket() to return false unless you're single-stepping the code.  Next time the code runs, the RX_BufferReset() call throws away the fragment of the message received earlier.  In the top snippet, the buffer reset makes it very hard to transmit any other message since it runs at interrupt time.  The reset randomly corrupts such a message. 
 Otherwise a bad idea in general, the controller could be hung but with the interrupts still functional.  This needs to be done in the main control loop.

Comment: the uart receive function is blocking, so on each cycle it should fetch the whole packet and not just a part, so it shouldn't matter if on the next cycle the buffer is reset. The WaitFullPacket function is simply an initial check of the start and end bytes to see if the packet has been received correctly, PacketReceive will then analyze the packet byte by byte to verify its integrity. Similarly in transmission, the buffers are reset every TPOLL which is however a very high value compared to the transmission time of the packet which is of the order of a few tens of bytes

Comment: I am convinced that the problem is in some error of the uart. I tried setting TPOLL to 20 milliseconds and TSILENT to 200 milliseconds and after about fifty packets on average (therefore 1 second, sometimes even two or sometimes even immediately) something went wrong

Comment: "*I am convinced that the problem is in some error of the uart.*" -- Then you don't have a programming question, and  you're posting at the wrong site. Vote to close.

Comment: You took a wrong interface for that. The protocol and feature you are looking for is called TCP/IP keepalive. You may implement it on UART with help of PPP.